# Angular ngRepeat - How to have multiple objects containing radio buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing some updates to a clients Ionic app but stuck on some binding.

There is a form with some fields including a couple of radio buttons.

E.g.

```
<div class="fields">
    <input ng-model="student.name" type="text" name="student_name" id="name" />

    <input ng-model="student.has_booked" type="radio" checked="checked" name="made_booking" id="made_booking_yes" value="1" />
</div>
```

The request for the update is to have a button that duplicates the details in this first form and add its to an array where the details can be used for another student as they are normally similar.

To do this I have a button that calls this method:

```
$scope.additionalStudents = []; // <-- for context of question

$scope.duplicateStudentDetails = function() {
    var firstStudent = angular.copy($scope.student);
    $scope.additionalStudents.push(firstStudent);
}
```

Then in my view:

```
<div class="fields" ng-repeat="(key, student) in additionalStudents track by $index">
    <input ng-model="student.name" type="text" name="student_name" id="name" />

    <input ng-model="student.has_booked" type="radio" checked="checked" name="made_booking" id="made_booking_yes" value="1" />
</div>
```

The issue I am having is that the name came be changed independently, but the checkbox always affects the original student. Im guessing this is because of the name attribute...

How do I go around this?

Comment: Probably because you have `$scope.student` already defined, use `ng-repeat="(key, stud) in additionalStudents`

Comment: @Sajal I was thinking of the same thing, but why it works correctly for the text box then?

Comment: @Lovelock You can't have same value for name attribute as you said. You must mention different name values

Comment: @Mr_Perfect That rings a bell, ill give it a whirl and see if its solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be two solutions to your problem.

**If your case is just to show the status and not to change the booking status**

Then, remove `name` attribute

**If you want change the booking status in future**

Better to have `input of type checkbox` with different names